# Determine where a catch block ends ASM

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

In ASM, I'm trying to determine the labels for a try-catch block.

Currently I have:

```
public void printTryCatchLabels(MethodNode method) {

    if (method.tryCatchBlocks != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < method.tryCatchBlocks.size(); ++i) {

            Label start = method.tryCatchBlocks.get(i).start.getLabel();
            Label end = method.tryCatchBlocks.get(i).end.getLabel();
            Label catch_start = method.tryCatchBlocks.get(i).handler.getLabel();

            System.out.println("try{      " + start.toString());
            System.out.println("}         " + end.toString());
            System.out.println("catch {   " + catch_start.toString());
            System.out.println("}         "  /*where does the catch block end?*/);

        }
    }

}
```

I'm trying to determine where the label is for the end of the catch block but I don't know how. Why do I need it? Because I want to "remove" try-catch blocks from the byte-code.

For example, I am trying to change:

```
public void test() {
    try {
        System.out.println("1");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //optionally rethrow e.
    }
    System.out.println("2");
}
```

to:

```
public void test() {
    System.out.println("1");
    System.out.println("2");
}
```

So to remove it, I thought that I could just get the labels and remove all instructions between the catch-start and the catch-end and then remove all the labels.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend reading the [JVM Spec §3.12. Throwing and Handling Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.12). It contains an example that is very simple but still exhibiting the problems with your idea:

> Compilation of try-catch constructs is straightforward. For example:
>
> ```
> void catchOne() {
>     try {
>         tryItOut();
>     } catch (TestExc e) {
>         handleExc(e);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> is compiled as:
>
> ```
> Method void catchOne()
> 0   aload_0             // Beginning of try block
> 1   invokevirtual #6    // Method Example.tryItOut()V
> 4   return              // End of try block; normal return
> 5   astore_1            // Store thrown value in local var 1
> 6   aload_0             // Push this
> 7   aload_1             // Push thrown value
> 8   invokevirtual #5    // Invoke handler method: 
>                         // Example.handleExc(LTestExc;)V
> 11  return              // Return after handling TestExc
> Exception table:
> From    To      Target      Type
> 0       4       5           Class TestExc
> ```

Here, the `catch` block ends with a `return` instruction, thus does not join with the original code flow. This, however, is not a required behavior. Instead, the compiled code could have a branch to the last `return` instruction in place of the `4 return` instruction, i.e.

```
Method void catchOne()
0:  aload_0
1:  invokevirtual #6   // Method tryItOut:()V
4:  goto          13
7:  astore_1
8:  aload_0
9:  aload_1
10: invokevirtual #5   // Method handleExc:(LTestExc;)V
13: return
Exception table:
From    To      Target      Type
   0     4           7      Class TestExc
```

(e.g. at least one Eclipse version compiled the example exactly this way)

But it could also be vice versa, having a branch to instruction `4` in place of the last `return` instruction.

```
Method void catchOne()
0   aload_0
1   invokevirtual #6    // Method Example.tryItOut()V
4   return
5   astore_1
6   aload_0
7   aload_1
8   invokevirtual #5   // Method Example.handleExc(LTestExc;)V
11  goto 4
Exception table:
From    To      Target      Type
0       4       5           Class TestExc
```

So you already have three possibilities to compile this simple example which doesn’t contain any conditionals. The conditional branches associated with loops or `if` instructions do not necessarily point to the instruction right after a conditional block of code. If that block of code would be followed by another flow control instruction, the conditional branch (the same applies to `switch` targets) could short-circuit the branch.

So it’s very hard to determine which code belongs to a `catch` block. On the byte code level, it doesn’t even have to be a contiguous block but may be interleaved with other code.

And at this time we didn’t even speak about [compiling `finally`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.13) and [`synchronized`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.14) or the newer [`try(…)` with resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement. They all end up creating exception handlers that look like `catch` blocks on the byte code level.

---

Since branch instructions within the exception handler might target code outside of the handler when recovering from the exception, traversing the code graph of an exception handler doesn’t help here as processing the branch instruction correctly requires the very information about the branch target you actually want to gather.

So the only way to handle this task is to do the *opposite*. You have to traverse the code graph from the beginning of the method for the non-exceptionally execution and consider every encountered instruction as not belonging to an exception handler. For the simple task of stripping exception handlers this is already sufficient as you simply have to retain all encountered instructions and drop all others.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you will have to do am execution flow analysis. In your example:

```
public void test() {
    try {                         // (1) try start
        System.out.println("1");
    }                             // (2) try end
    catch(Exception e) {          
        //optionally rethrow e.   // (3) catch start
    }                             // (4) catch end
    System.out.println("2");      // (5) continue execution
}
```

Graphically it will look like this:

```
---(1)-+--(2)---------------------+
       |                          +--(5 execution path merged)
       +--(3 branched here)--(4)--+
```

So, you need to build a graph of the code blocks and then remove nodes related to (3) and (4). Currently ASM doesn't provide execution flow analysis tools, though some users reported that they build such tools on top of ASM's tree package.

Comment: But how do I find (4)?

Comment: By following chain of instructions trough all possible branches, conditional jumps and nested try/catch blocks.

Answer (score 1):

There are relatively common situations in which the end of the catch block is easy to detect. I'm assuming here that we are using a Java compiler.

- when the try block (between the start and end label), ends with a GOTO(joinLabel). If the block does not throw an exception or return always, or break/continue out of a surrounding loop, then it will end with GOTO which points to the end of last handler.
- same for catch blocks which are not the last block, they will jump over the handlers to follow using a GOTO which can help you identify the end of the last handler. So if the try block does not have such a GOTO, you might find one in the other handlers.

  - these non-last catch blocks can be detected by comparing the handler labels of TRYCATCH instructions with the same start and end labels. The start label of the next handler acts as the (exclusive) end of the previous handler.

Answer (score 0):

At the bytecode level, excepting handling is essentially a goto. The code doesn't have to be structured, or even have a well defined catch block at all. And even if you are dealing only with normally compiled Java code, it is still quite complicated once you consider the possibilities of try with resources or complicated control flow structures inside the catch block.

If you just want to remove code associated with the "catch block", I would recommend simply removing the associated exception handler entry and then doing a dead code elimination pass. You can probably find an existing DCE pass somewhere (for example, Soot), or you could write your own.